# How to access the member of a different class form another class in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file called A.js.
And in this file, I have a method doing this:

```
getSummaryRows() {
    const planRows = Plans.summray(this.state.selectedPlanSize, !this.state.selectedDB);
```

Now, I want to use the above defined ***planRows*** into another file called B.js.

I tried using it, but couldn't. Can someone tell me what's the correct way?

Comment: Where is B in the component tree, relative to A?

Comment: need more details on interaction model of components

Answer (score 1):

Where is B in the component tree, relative to A?

- If B is a child of A, pass it as a prop.
- If B is the parent or ancestor of A, you should probably move this code up to B and pass it down as a prop to A.

  - An alternative depending on the circumstances is to have B pass a function as a prop to A, and then have A call that function passing in the data.
- If B is a sibling or cousin of A, move this code up to their common ancestor, and pass it as a prop to both.
- In all cases, if these components are far apart, consider using context instead of props so you don't need to pass props through all the intermediate components.

Comment: I guess they are siblings.
I can't move the code around. Can you elaborate a more please?

Comment: I'll happily elaborate, but you will need to first. Please edit your question to have more details describing their relationship, how they are used, and what the restrictions are that prevent you from moving code.

Comment: @Damanpreet eveything in this answer is the right way to do these things in React. If you still can't [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) the React tree, you might want to consider using context or go for a state management solution like Redux.